# How do I get an element from JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, decoding

I have this output from a JSON. How can I get one element (for example "etternavn" ) into a PHP variable. This is the output I get for the whole thing:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [hitLinesBeforeFilter] => 1 
    [userID] => 632 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [listing] => stdClass Object ( 
            [table] => listing 
            [id] => 1402864 
            [duplicates] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [table] => listing 
                    [id] => 1402864:0 
                    [idlinje] => D1FIJFT000 
                    [tlfnr] => 41428798 
                    [etternavn] => Bumpy Bones Interactive Cornelius Gutsu 
                    [veinavn] => Hans Nielsen Hauges vei 
                    [husnr] => 48F 
                    [postnr] => 1523 
                    [virkkode] => N 
                    [apparattype] => M 
                    [kilde] => D 
                    [foretaksnr] => 998209609 
                    [bransjekode] => 15636 
                    [prioritet] => 0 
                    [kommunenr] => 104 
                    [poststed] => Moss 
                    [kommune] => Moss 
                    [fylke] => Østfold 
                    [landsdel] => Ø 
                    [bransjebokmaal] => Internettdesign og programmering 
                    [bransjenynorsk] => Internett design og programmering 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [dummy] => 
)
```

The PHP code is the following:

```
$json = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url, 'UTF-8'));
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data->result);
```

I have tried echo $data->etternavn;

I know this might be a simple question, sorry. I'm not good with coding.

Comment: You could turn it to an assoc (`json_decode($json, true)`) if you find objects confusing.

Comment: Try this `$data = json_decode(json_encode($json),true);
print_r($data['result']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```html
<?php


  $json = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url, 'UTF-8'));
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  print_r($data['result'][1]['listing']['duplicates'][0]['etternavn']);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to traverse through this complex structure. To get *etternavn* you need to do this:

```php
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->result->{1}->listing->duplicates->{0}->etternavn;
```

Or as suggested in comments, pass next parameter of json_decode to `true`. Which will convert it into array.

```php
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['result'][1]['listing']['duplicates'][0]['etternavn'];
```